# Hide flow in node red

Tags: node.js, node-red

I am using node-red editor and I defined a flow (flow-A) which has some linked nodes. This (flow-A) is triggered to run when node-red starts.

I want to hide (flow-A) on the node-red editor, that means keep it hidden to any user.

Instead I want this (flow-A) to run internally. Sometimes, we want things to run in the background and be hidden to users. Is there anyway to do this or make it happen?

Ps: When hidden it should not be visible to any user, meaning it is defined once only to run in the background.

Answer (score 2):

Node-RED doesn't provide any built-in way of hiding flows.

One possible approach would be to embed node-red into your own custom node.js application that can intercept the requests to the `/flows` HTTP admin endpoint and filter the flow configuration sent to the editor. But that is quite involved and there is no documentation for how to do it.